# Blue line appears when animating text in p link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a simple [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) animate function to animate some text to the left, if the text is clicked.

```
jQuery(this).animate({ marginLeft: 50 }, 'slow');
```

the markup is pretty much just a `p`-tag. When I'm animating it, I can see those weird blue line appearing on Safari:

[image]

The line has the exact same length, the animation does. Anyone of you know why? I really need some help, as I cannot find out the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is this only on Safari? I can't seem to replicate the problem on Chrome. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkfhkar3/1/) is my fiddle.

Comment: @MonicaOlejniczak Yes it is on Safari, not on Chrome.

Comment: @supersize can't replicate it on Safari (Mac) either => [https://jsfiddle.net/k6vqdL2a/](https://jsfiddle.net/k6vqdL2a/). Please create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: @supersize looks like the `font-family` in your class `.p_inner_active` causing the trouble. The line disappears when you disable `font-family`. It may be something to do with the custom font. I am not sure though.